# Why the thread pool can launch my tasks with the same priority not in the same order I posted them?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I consistently run three operations through the thread pool. They have the same priority. However, the order of their execution is not always the one in which I ran them. Why does it happen?

I expected the thread pool will launch my tasks in the same order in which they will be posted by me into the query queue of the thread pool (if they have the same priority).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadsLearning {

    class Foo {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {

            Console.WriteLine("Main method works...");

            Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "Bob" };

            CallContext.LogicalSetData("name", foo);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Console.WriteLine("1: Name = {0}",
            CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

            ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Console.WriteLine("2: Name = {0}",
                CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

            ExecutionContext.RestoreFlow();

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Console.WriteLine("3: Name = {0}",
                CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

            Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> for exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output can be:

```
Main method works...
Hit <Enter> for exit...
2: Name =
1: Name = Bob
3: Name = Bob
```

or

```
Main method works...
1: Name = Bob
2: Name =
3: Name = Bob
Hit <Enter> for exit...
```

**UPD**

I tried to do the same with the stream and get the same problem:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadsLearning {

    class Foo {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, 0x1000, true)) {
                    sw.WriteLine("Main method works...");

                    Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "Bob" };

                    CallContext.LogicalSetData("name", foo);

                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => sw.WriteLine("1: Name = {0}",
                        CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

                    ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();

                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => sw.WriteLine("2: Name = {0}",
                        CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

                    ExecutionContext.RestoreFlow();

                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => sw.WriteLine("3: Name = {0}",
                        CallContext.LogicalGetData("name")));

                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // Postpone the ws.Dispose() call.
                }

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stream length: {0} bytes", ms.Length);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Data: \n{0}", sr.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> for exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that the three threads don't reach the point that produces the output in the order you queue them doesn't mean that they aren't started in the order you queue them in. Remember that it's actually machine code getting executed, not C# code, so one line of your code actually results in numerous instructions for the machine to execute.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What if I will put into the thread pool qwery queue the many little tasks which are to write some info into the stream (instead of console output)? At this case the order of writting is very important for me otherwice document format will be wrong.

Comment: OS does not provide any guaranty to fairly split processor time between threads. Even if `ThreadPool` will guaranty that work items will start in the same order as them queued (which it does not), you still have no guaranty that them finish their work in the same order as them started.

Comment: If you need ordered parallel processing you can't use QueueUserWorkItem. You should look at the PLINQ extension methods and it's `Ordered()` extension tto do your parallel work.

Comment: Also, why does it matter what the order is?

Comment: Thank you. I will to learn it.

Comment: @TanveerBadar For example the threads can write info into the stream (the document instance) which has some predefined format.

Comment: I added **UPD** section - it was my second variant of the same attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Threadpool uses a Queue to enter "things to do" into and take "things to do" out from.

when adding a task it will place it in a available slot, just have a look at the tread window in Visual Studio, you will see that it isn't a queue it is a fixed size array (can grow if becomes bigger) See image from "JustDecompile"

[image: Pushing a storage structure holding your action on the "thread pool's To-Do list"]

If your logic demands that you execute step 1 then step 2 you can't use that method, the nature of "multi threading" is that you start something in the background that is in some way isolated, a "statement of work", works as designed, runs the task as soon as resources become available.

When looking at that behaviour, what will give you the expected flow is [Task.ContinueWith(action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__), you can chain actions together as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx).